# JQuery code only working on firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMbaMW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>About me</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/aboutme.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/js/typed.js"></script>


<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: ["Jack.", "a Programmer.","a Gamer.","an Enthusiast who has a passion for Knowledge, Experiences, Challenges and Food."],
         typeSpeed: 20,
            loop: false,
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            callback: function(){ foo(); }
        });


        function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
    });

</script>

</head>

<header>
 <p>So, who am I?</p>
</header>
<body>
<div class ="mtext">
<h1 id="pretyped"> I am <h1 id="typed"></h1></h1>

<br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the thing is this only works on my default browser, ie. firefox, it just upright doesnt work on anything else. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you're loading the `typed.js` library via GitHub, which doesn't have the correct MIME type. I'd recommend using something like [RawGit](http://rawgit.com) to serve the library, or just download and load it locally.

Using RawGit the URL would look something like https://rawgit.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/js/typed.js for development and https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/js/typed.js for production.

I've created a JSFiddle you can reference [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pinjasaur/v9pve2w5/).

Comment: omfg, thank you so much the rawgit link fixed it. your the best <3